# How to retrieve POSIX time stamp from this string?

Tags: r, posixct

I have strings like the following:

```
"{u'iso': u'2015-05-12T12:43:17.512Z', u'__type': u'Date'}"
```

I'd like to convert them to times. I tried the following:

```
time_format_string = "{u'iso': u'%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S', u'__type': u'Date'}"
strptime(test_string, time_format_string)
```

This gives back an `NA` with no error message. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You omitted the `"Z"` after the seconds in your format string. However, the result is still `NA` if you add the `"Z"`, which looks like it might be because you have fractional seconds and you use `"%S"` instead of `"%OS"`.

```
options(digits.secs=3)  # print fractional seconds
test_string = "{u'iso': u'2015-05-12T12:43:17.512Z', u'__type': u'Date'}"
time_format_string = "{u'iso': u'%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ', u'__type': u'Date'}"
strptime(test_string, time_format_string)
#[1] NA
time_format_string = "{u'iso': u'%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%OSZ', u'__type': u'Date'}"
strptime(test_string, time_format_string)
#[1] "2015-05-12 12:43:17.512 CDT"
```

Regardless, this is easily avoidable because you do not need to specify anything in your format string after the last time component you want (see Details in `?strptime`: "*Each input string is processed as far as necessary for the format specified: any trailing characters are ignored*").

```
time_format_string = "{u'iso': u'%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S"
strptime(test_string, time_format_string)
#[1] "2015-05-12 12:43:17 CDT"
```

If you want to retain the fractional seconds, you should use `"%OS"` instead of `"%S"`. You should also explicitly set the timezone to avoid the times being parsed in your machine's local timezone. I set the timezone to `"UTC"` because that's most likely what the `"Z"` after the seconds represents.

```
time_format_string = "{u'iso': u'%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%OS"
strptime(test_string, time_format_string, tz="UTC")
#[1] "2015-05-12 12:43:17.512 UTC"
```